# I can't install ubuntu 20.04 lts on an asus tuf laptop

Tags: asus

I can not install ubuntu 20.04 lts on a laptop asus tuf, try to install other previous versions but it still has the same problem it hangs when installing the most I get was to make the partitions but suddenly it hangs or I cannot start the system in test mode

Comment: try to add more details: What kind of error message? Wher does ist stop? is there enough space on disk? did you try to install without or with UEFI? my Tip: Try to install from MinimalCD (!) this avoids the UEFI trap. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Did you verify the ISO downloaded accurately as per https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu ? If so, test w/ a Xubuntu 18.04 LiveUSB: Download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . Check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu . Make the LiveUSB (Ubuntu) https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 . Install per https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't even load into the setup program for Ubuntu 20.04 through my USB - the laptop just shut down immediately like being overheated/overpowered
Asus TUF FX504GE (i7 8750H/1050 Ti) by the way - latest 318 BIOS

I selected the safe graphics install option in the GRUB menu and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

change the SATA mode to AHCI and turn of the secure boot and try installing the Ubuntu 20.04.
First install it with safe graphics then after installing OS completely install the NVIDIA drivers and you are good to go